# Android - how to save CheckBox enabled state

Tags: android, settings

I have some PreferenceActivity and there are some CheckBoxes.

```
<PreferenceScreen
        android:key="prefGraphValues"
        android:title="@string/pref_graph_values"
        android:persistent="false" >
         <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="Temp.Dry"
            android:summary="@string/pref_graph_value_temp_dry_summary"
            android:title="@string/pref_graph_value_temp_dry" >
        </CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Somwhere in code I have something like this:

```
checkBox.setEnabled(false);
```

But when I close this activity and later launch it, checkBox is enabled. Can I save this state?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your persistent property to true.

```
android:persistent="true"
```

Actual, if you assign it to `false` it means that preference won't store value(s) to the SharedPreferences and this is reason why your state is not saved in "next launch".

Comment: Yes, this property save a state of checkBox that is checked or not, but not state that is enabled or disabled. I dont know how to do this. Some another ideas?

Comment: @Papaja so save state explicitly to SharedPreferences. When you set enabled to false, save it to SharedPreferences with key for example `Temp.DryIsNotEnabled` do you know how to achieve it? or you need some code example?

Comment: yes i know how to achieve it but i think that is another way(easier) that API implements for this occasions. But yes this is solution for me :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the change to sharedpreference and next time the checkbox will retrieve the value by the key from sharedpreference.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
sp.edit().putInt(your_key, your_value).apply();
```